# WPF binding to a property not in the DataGrid ItemSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am wondering how I can bind a DataGrid DataGridTemplateColumn to a property in that isn't in the DataGrid ItemSource, but the property is within the same DataContext of the Itemsource?

XAML

```
        // I am trying to bind the Visibility property to a property called Visible
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Apply" Visibility="{Binding source Visible}">

        // However the visible property doesnt exist inside the resource cvsCustomers
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomerCollection}}"
```

C#

```
    // But they both live in the same ViewModel i.e. DataContext      
    private Visibility m_Visible = Visibility.Hidden;

    public Visibility Visible
    {
       get { return m_Visible; }
       set { m_Visible = value; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Customer> m_CustomerCollection = null;

    public ObservableCollection<Customer> CustomerCollection
    {
       get { return m_CustomerCollection; }
       set { m_CustomerCollection = value; }
    }
```

Can this be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: Although you show us a property `CustomerCollection` in your view model class, you are binding the ItemsSource to a collection that resides in a ResourceDictionary, with key "CustomerCollection". That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Sorry - I explain, the collection is from a CollectionViewSource as I need to filter on the CustomerCollection.

Comment: Ok. Provided that the DataContext of the DataGrid is an instance of your ViewModel class, you should be able to bind the Visibility by `Visibility="{Binding Visible}"` or `Visibility="{Binding Path=Visible}"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Datagrid columns does not comes under the visual tree of the `DataGrid`. hence you will need to use the BindingProxy to make ViewModel accessible to your `DataGridTemplateColumn`. I have explained how to create and use `BindingProxy` in the answer below:

[Bind ViewModel property to DataGridComboBoxColum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155649/wpf-datagridcomboboxcolum-weirdness/19156021#19156021)

Once you have setup the BindingProxy you can bind your DataGridTemplateColumn visiblity as

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Apply" Visibility="{Binding Path=Data.Visible, Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}"
```

Comment: Why did they (Microsoft) have to design it like this? But Works prefect, thanks